# Why does scala not infer the right type when wrapping EitherT?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

Here's the code:

```
// eventually will be an implicit class with extension methods
class EitherTWrapper [L,R] (ei: EitherT[Future,L,R])

new EitherTWrapper(??? : EitherT[Future,Nothing,Boolean])
```

Fails to compile with:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : cats.data.EitherT[scala.concurrent.Future,Nothing,Boolean]
 required: cats.data.EitherT[scala.concurrent.Future,L,Boolean]
Note: Nothing <: L, but class EitherT is invariant in type A.
You may wish to define A as +A instead. (SLS 4.5)
```

It works fine if I provide the types explicitly, like this:

```
new EitherTWrapper[Nothing,Boolean](??? : EitherT[Future,Nothing,Boolean])
```

Which would work, except that I can't do that if I'm trying to make it an implicit class.

I expected this to work. How do I define a class that can wrap an EitherT?

Comment: Does it work if you use a def in a companion object to do the construction, rather than using new directly?

Comment: As the error suggests, does `class EitherTWrapper [+L,R] (ei: EitherT[Future,L,R])` not work?

Comment: @JamesWhiteley I think the error is referring to A in EitherT, so I didn't even consider changing it in EitherTWrapper... but you're right, changing it on the wrapper did fix that issue (it also brought on other issues because i had methods that were using A in contravariant position, but was able to figure out a way to get those to work too). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it's a known scala compiler bug (limitation?):
https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/9453

It seems there's 2 workarounds:

- Make the type covariant on the wrapper (not great because now the wrapper has a different variance behavior than the thing being wrapped and only works if the type param is not being used contravariantly).
- Treat the version of `EitherT` with `Nothing` specially, by creating a separate wrapper for it. This works even when trying to use the wrappers as implicit classes.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, changing your wrapper to `class EitherTWrapper [+L,R] (ei: EitherT[Future,L,R])` will fix your compilation errors.

Your error states that `Nothing <: L, but class EitherT is invariant in type A.` - this means that `Nothing` is a subtype of `L`, so declaring `L` is illegal since it implies you explicitly want `L` not its subtypes (i.e. `L` is invariant).

Declaring something as `+L` makes it covariant, making what you want possible. Read up more on variance in the scala docs: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html

The reason the below code (from the docs) works is because Scala's `List` is defined as `List[+A]`, meaning that you can also pass in `List[Cat]` and `List[Dog]` to a function that takes a `List[Animal]`:

```scala
abstract class Animal {
  def name: String
}
case class Cat(name: String) extends Animal
case class Dog(name: String) extends Animal

object CovarianceTest extends App {
  def printAnimalNames(animals: List[Animal]): Unit = {
    animals.foreach { animal =>
      println(animal.name)
    }
  }

  val cats: List[Cat] = List(Cat("Whiskers"), Cat("Tom"))
  val dogs: List[Dog] = List(Dog("Fido"), Dog("Rex"))

  printAnimalNames(cats)
  // Whiskers
  // Tom

  printAnimalNames(dogs)
  // Fido
  // Rex
}
```

[On Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/VSsaBwJsSUipPvhDJUToQw)

Comment: My problem is not really variance, but inference. When the types are provided explicitly, the original code compiles correctly. Changing the variance is a workaround for an inference problem. I think the problem has more to do with the `Nothing` type and how it's treated specially by the compiler. Will have to return to this later with more info.